# using date variable inside sed command

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am storing date inside a variable and using that in the sed as below.

```
DateTime=`date "+%m/%d/%Y"`

Plc_hldr1=`head -$i place_holder.txt | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }'`
Plc_hldr2=`head -$i place_holder.txt | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }'`

sed "s/$Plc_hldr1/$DateTime/;s/$Plc_hldr2/$Total/" html_format.htm >> /u/raskar/test/html_final.htm
```

While running the sed command I am getting the below error.

```
sed: 0602-404 Function s/%%DDMS1RT%%/01/02/2014/;s/%%DDMS1C%%/1235/ cannot be parsed.
```

I suppose this is happening as the date contains the following output which includes slashes '/'

```
01/02/2014
```

I tried with different quotes around the date. How do I make it run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the separator to something else that won't appear in your patterns, for example:

```
sed "s?$Plc_hldr1?$DateTime?;s?$Plc_hldr2?$Total?"
```

Comment: thanks!! it worked. I didnt' know I could use any other separator :)..thnks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Not the direct quertion but replace

```
Plc_hldr1=`head -$i place_holder.txt | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }'`
Plc_hldr2=`head -$i place_holder.txt | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }'`
```

by

```
Plc_hldr1=`sed -n "$i {s/ .*//p;q}"`
Plc_hldr2=`sed -n "$i {s/[^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}\([^ ]\{1,\}\) .*/\1/p;q}"`
```

and with aix/ksh

```
sed -n "$i {s/\([^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}[^ ]\{1,\}\) .*/\1/p;q}" | read Plc_hldr1 Plc_hldr2
```